# Write custom timestamps to InfluxDB with Python

Tags: python, influxdb

I'm currently struggling with a basic function of the influx_client in Python. I have a set of time series data which I want to add into an influxdb on a different client. My current code looks kinda like this:

```
client = InfluxDBClient(url=f"http://{ip}:{port_db}", token=token, org=org)    
write_api = client.write_api(write_options=ASYNCHRONOUS)

p = Point("title_meas").field("column_data", value_data)
write_api.write(bucket=bucket, org=org, record=p)
```

Now I got a specific timestamp for each point I want to use as the InfluxDB keys/timestamps but whatever I try - it keeps on adding the system time of my host device (But as I'm working with historical data I need to adjust the timespecs). How I can achieve my custom timestamps or is there a easier way instead of using the `Point` method adding my data line by line... something like a Pandas dataframe maybe?
Thankful for every advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can write via line protocol, Point objects, Pandas Dataframe, or json Dictionary. All are viable methods.

If you care about throughput line protocol is the fastest, but if tiny speed differences are not important just use whatever you want. I highly recommend reading  [this](https://influxdb-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#write). The "tag" you are looking to modify on the influx datapoint is called "_time".

To add it to a Point do:

```
p = Point("title_meas").field("column_data", value_data).time('2021-08-09T18:04:56.865943'))
```

or json dictionary protocol:

```
p = {'measurement':'title_meas', 'time': '2021-08-09T18:04:56.865943',
 'tags':{'sometag': 'sometag'},
 'fields':{'column_data': value_data}
}
```

Easiest way to ensure timestamps are what you expect is to use **UTC/ISO format**.